# React collect all properties as one props and put it into component or NOT?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm reading this following code from https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config

```
const RouteWithSubRoutes = route => (
  <Route
    path={route.path}
    render={props => (
      // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
      <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />
    )}
  />
);

const RouteConfigExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/tacos">Tacos</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/sandwiches">Sandwiches</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      {routes.map((route, i) => <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />)}
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Please look at the first line, why it's not this:

```
const RouteWithSubRoutes = ({route}) => (
```

As I know, this arrow function should get one parameter which we often call it as props, which should be a collection include all properties that be put in. In this case the props should include 'key' and all of properties of 'route'.

In the component of the arrow function, the RouteWithSubRouters, we should filter the useful properties from the collection props, such as route, so we write the parameters as ({route}).

Am I get it wrong? Why it show error when I change it to ({route})?

===================================================================

Thanks to all! Now I know the parameter magic. I change code as following:

```
const RouteWithSubRoutes = (routeProps) => {
    console.log(routeProps.aaa)
    return (
  <Route
    path={routeProps.path}
    render={props => (
      // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
      <routeProps.component {...props} routes={routeProps.routes} />
    )}
  />
);

const RouteConfigExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/tacos">Tacos</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/sandwiches">Sandwiches</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      {routes.map((route, i) => <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} aaa="bbb" {...route} />)}
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

I get the print 'bbb'~. 
It's easier to understand if the parameter is named as 'props'.

Comment: Consider adding `const routes = ...` to the example, it's not clear without navigating to external link.

Comment: There is other good enough answers, so just responding shortly at `Why it show error when I change it to ({route})?`: routes is props with other name. When you use curly braces you are deconstructing props to have the specific prop from props. If you change route for {route} you are changing route for route.route. That's why you can't do that and it shows an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code `route` is an object that contains values that have to be used to create `<Route>`. Since `props` name is ambiguous and is used within same component, it could be defined for explicitness as:

```
const RouteWithSubRoutes = routeProps => (
  <Route
    path={routeProps.path}
    render={props => (
      // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
      <routeProps.component {...props} routes={routeProps.routes} />
    )}
  />
);
```

Or with destructuring (`component` needs to be renamed to upper-case):

```
const RouteWithSubRoutes = ({ path, routes, component: Component }) => (
  <Route
    path={path}
    render={props => (
      <Component {...props} routes={routes} />
    )}
  />
);
```

`const RouteWithSubRoutes = ({route}) => (...)` would be a mistake because `routeProps` object that `RouteWithSubRoutes` receives doesn't have `route` property.

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
{routes.map((route, i) => <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />)}
```

specifically in `{...route}`, you are not passing the component `RouteWithSubRoutes` a prop named `route`. By using the spread syntax ([More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)), you are passing every property of the `route`object as an individual prop. Thus, the first parameter of the render function does not actually contain a `route` object, it contains `key` and every one of the properties of `route`.

For example, if the route object looks like this:

```
{
    something: "value",
    somethingElse: "otherValue",
}
```

Then doing

```
{routes.map((route, i) => <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />)}
```

is equivalent to doing

```
{routes.map((route, i) => <RouteWithSubRoutes 
    key={i} 
    something={route.something}
    somethingElse={route.somethingElse} 
/>)}
```

What you actually seem to want to do is to:

```
{routes.map((route, i) => <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} route={route} />)}
```

Where you pass your `route` object as the prop named `route`, allowing you to do:

```
const RouteWithSubRoutes = ({route}) => (
    //THE RENDER OF THE ROUTE HERE
)
```

---

When you say:

> As I know, this arrow function should get one parameter which we often call it as props, which should be a collection include all properties that be put in. In this case the props should include 'key' and all of properties of 'route'.

you are understanding how the spread syntax works. Props should include `key`and all of the properties of `route`, and `route` does not include a property named `route` unless your actual `route`object contains inside another object named `route`, like so:

```
{
    ...
    route: {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```